# asyncio.gather with generator expression

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Why doesn't asyncio.gather work with a generator expression?

```
import asyncio

async def func():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

# Works
async def call3():
    x = (func() for x in range(3))
    await asyncio.gather(*x)

# Doesn't work
async def call3():
    await asyncio.gather(func() for x in range(3))

# Works
async def call3():
    await asyncio.gather(*[func() for x in range(3)])

asyncio.run(call3())
```

The second variant gives:

```
[...]
  File "test.py", line 13, in <genexpr>
    await asyncio.gather(func() for x in range(3))
RuntimeError: Task got bad yield: <coroutine object func at 0x10421dc20>
```

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
await asyncio.gather(func() for x in range(3))
```

This doesn't work because this is passing *the generator object* as argument to `gather`. `gather` doesn't expect an *iterable*, it expects coroutines as individual arguments. Which means you need to unpack the generator.

Comment: Ah of course, now I see it. Somehow I figured that unpacking of generator arguments was standard behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unpack the generator:

```py
await asyncio.gather(*(func() for i in range(10)))  # star expands generator
```

We must expand it because [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) expects a list of arguments (i.e. `asyncio.gather(coroutine0, coroutine1, coroutine2, coroutine3)`), not an iterable

Answer (score 0):

Python uses `*`/`**` for both 'un-packing' and just 'packing' based on whether it's used for variable assignment or not.

```
def foo(*args,**kwargs):...
```

In this case, all non-keyworded args are getting put into a tuple `args` and all kwargs are getting packed into a new dictionary. A single variable passed in still gets packed into a tuple(`*`) or dict(`**`).

This is kind of a hybrid

```
first,*i_take_the_rest,last = range(10)
>>> first=0,i_take_the_rest=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],last=9
*a,b = range(1)
>>> a=[],b=0
```

But here it unpacks:

```
combined_iterables = [*range(10),*range(3)]
merged_dict = {**first_dict,**second_dict}
```

So basically if it's on the left side of the equals or if it's used in a function/method definition like `*foo` it's packing stuff into a list or tuple (respectively).  In comprehensions, however, it has the unpacking behavior.